# How to create play/pause button in SlideJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I need to create a simple play/pause button using the [SlideJS library](http://slidesjs.com/).
I've tried to follow the documentation, using a basic example and I came with something like this:

HTML Code:

```
<a id="play">play</a> 

<div id="slides">
    <div class="slides_container">
        <div>
            <h1>Slide 1</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>Slide 2</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>Slide 3</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>Slide 4</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
    $(function(){
        $("#slides").slides();

        $("#play").click(function () { 
            $("slides").slides({ play: 1000 }); 
        }); 
    });
```

Nevertheless, this is not working, and I just can't find out how to make it work

Answer (score 0):

You are aiming an element with its id attribute ... The selector for this is '#YOUR_ID'

you forgot the "#"

```
$('#slides').slides({ play: 1000 });
```

Comment: ... jQuery tried to look for a '<slides>' html element and as a result, it failed.

Comment: Well, you're actually right, I forgot to write the '#'. Somehow I forgot to write it when I formulated the question. But still.. it's not doing the right thing.. when I click the button #play , the slides repeates the numbers several times, and it practically goes crazy..

Comment: Your code seams to be likely adding several timers which leads to collision (it goes crazy). I think the library did not make possible to assign an element to control the slider behaviour ... you might need to implement it yourself :( ...  There are many options though, one of them is a pause option but only the prev/next and pagination buttons will trigger pause ....

Comment: Ok,in that case I guess I'll start using another similar library with this play/pause button implementation included. Thanks for your help

Comment: Guys Im looking for the same thing...goto desired slide via JS